# Previous button in the Stack Exchange Android app

Tags: bug, android-app

This must be somewhere between a bug and a feature request: I wish the Previous button too me back to the last visited pages.

Currently, hitting the prev button on my phone will take me back to the app's higher hierarchical page/menu, regardless of the pages I'd been through, resulting in my losing track of interesting stuff I want to come back to.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: Samsung
- Device Model: SM-G935F
- OS Version: 7.0 (G935FXXU1DQB7)